# Pusher for Java Stops working

Tags: java, api, websocket, pusher

So, I've been working on this for a while now, and have no idea what to do.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import com.pusher.client.Pusher;
import com.pusher.client.channel.Channel;
import com.pusher.client.channel.ChannelEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.channel.SubscriptionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionState;
import com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionStateChange;

public class Testic 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                // Create a new Pusher instance
                Pusher pusher = new Pusher("de504dc5763aeef9ff52");


                    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() +
                                               " from " + change.getPreviousState());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("There was a problem connecting!");
                        }
                    }, ConnectionState.ALL);

                    // Subscribe to a channel
                    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("order_book", new ChannelEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName) {
                            System.out.println("Subscribed!");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, String data) {
                            System.out.println("desilo se");
                        }
                    }, "bids", "asks");

                    // Bind to listen for events called "my-event" sent to "my-channel"
                    channel.bind("data", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
                            System.out.println("Received event with data: " + data);
                        }
                    });



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

I am trying to [read websocket API from Bitstamp](https://www.bitstamp.net/websocket/) for live order book. When I run it, it just says: `State changed to CONNECTING from DISCONNECTED`. It does not "loop" but just stops. I installed pusher dependencies as said [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client).

I really have no idea what to do.

Comment: The Pusher Java Client doesn't auto-reconnect. You can see an example of doing auto-reconnect here: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example/blob/master/src/com/pusher/android/example/MainActivity.java#L112 However, this won't ensure that you connection. Also, why did the connection fail? The `onError` callback may provide additional information. See https://github.com/pusher/pusher-android-example/blob/master/src/com/pusher/android/example/MainActivity.java#L115

Comment: @leggetter I am sorry, but I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say. My problem is that program does not do anything, it just goes through and terminates it. I read your examples but since I am new to pusher, I couldn't make it work. Could you please help me write code for simple program that will just read data using following parameters: 

CHANNEL: order_book, EVENT: data, PUSHER KEY: de504dc5763aeef9ff52

Thanks for response, I am really looking forward to your answer :)